# Dynamic order direction

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, case

I writing a SP that accepts as parameters column to sort and direction.

I don't want to use dynamic SQL.

The problem is with setting the direction parameter.

This is the partial code:

```
SET @OrderByColumn = 'AddedDate'
SET @OrderDirection = 1;

…

ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), AddedDate)
        WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Visible' THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), Visible)
        WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBy
        WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Title' THEN Title    
    END
```

Comment: I would recommend picking conversion pattern for AddedDate that makes sure that the character strings will sort in date order. I believe the default convert can change with locality settings. Better to explicitly define and be safe.

Comment: Does  it apply to some other types? Or just the DATE?

Comment: Numbers are also going to be a problem. For example converting 10, 1 and 2 to varchar will give you a sort of '1', '10', '2'. I imagine you are converting Visible and AddedDate to varchar because a CASE has to return all the same type, correct?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could have two near-identical `ORDER BY` items, one `ASC` and one `DESC`, and extend your `CASE` statement to make one or other of them always equal a single value:

```
ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 0 THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), AddedDate)
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Visible' THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), Visible)
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBy
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Title' THEN Title
           END
      END ASC,
      CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), AddedDate)
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Visible' THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), Visible)
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBy           
                WHEN @OrderByColumn = 'Title' THEN Title
           END
      END DESC
```

Comment: can you please answer the same question i asked  Alex Black in comment?

Comment: You're just doing ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 DESC (meaning order by Column1 ascending, then by Column2 descending) but instead of Column1 and Column2 you've got an expression for each.

Comment: if AddedDate is a datetime column you must use _CONVERT(char(23),AddedDate,121)_ or it will not sort properly

Comment: @GaryMcGill - In **MS SQL 2008 R2** I have found I get an equivalent of `ORDER BY 1 ASC, Title DESC`, where `1` is the position of the column in the select list, meaning in this case it would order by `col[1]` first. Would you agree?

Comment: @Scotty.NET: I don't think so, no. You are correct that ORDER BY 1 orders by the first column, but I think that only works when the ORDER BY argument is a literal number. If the argument is an expression, then the behavior is different. For example, `ORDER BY 1+1` does *not* order by column 2. (In fact it does not change the order at all, since the *value of the expression* is the same for all rows).

Comment: @GaryMcGill - I have been able to get it working using `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN NULL` (I got an error about converting  int to nvarchar when sorting by nvarchar field and using `1` instead of `NULL`. Interestingly you cannot use `NULL` or `1+1` normally in an `ORDER BY`. E.G. `SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY 1+1` or `NULL` or any other 'constant expression' results in an error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12):

You can simplify the CASE by using ROW_NUMBER which sorts your data and effectively converts it into a handy integer format. Especially since the question is tagged SQL Server 2005

This also expands easily enough to deal with secondary and tertiary sorts

I've used multiplier to again simplify the actual select statement and reduce the chance of RBAR evaluation in the ORDER BY

```
DECLARE @multiplier int;

SELECT @multiplier = CASE @Direction WHEN 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END;

SELECT
     Columns you actually want
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         Columns you actually want,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AddedDate) AS AddedDateSort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Visible) AS VisibleSort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AddedBy) AS AddedBySort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title) AS TitleSort
    FROM
         myTable
    WHERE
         MyFilters...
    ) foo
ORDER BY
     CASE @OrderByColumn
        WHEN 'AddedDate' THEN AddedDateSort
        WHEN 'Visible' THEN VisibleSort    
        WHEN 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBySort
        WHEN 'Title' THEN TitleSort
     END * @multiplier;
```

Comment: Have you noticed any performance hit with doing multiple `ROW_NUMBER()`'s? I understand everyones data is different.

Comment: @Scotty.NET, I was worried about the performance of row_number, after some tests the row_number implementation looks slightly better then the multiple cases in order by clause, except when you need a slice of the data.

Indeed, the best result I´ve found was with just one rownumber over the cases - [here is a small gist with my queries](https://gist.github.com/thluiz/228c9e496322695e66213815aa80254e).

Comment: One can avoid duplicating column names by inlining the `row_number()` call into the `case` statement:  `when 'AddedDate' then row_number() over (order by AddedDate) * @sortMultiplier`

Answer (score 6):

This works fine for me – (`where`, `order by`, `direction`, `Pagination`)

```
parameters

@orderColumn  int ,
@orderDir  varchar(20),
@start  int ,
@limit  int


select * from items

order by 

CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 0 AND @orderdir = 'desc' THEN items.[CategoryName]  END DESC,    
CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 0 AND @orderdir = 'asc'  THEN items.[CategoryName]  END ASC,    
CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 1 AND @orderdir = 'desc' THEN items.[CategoryValue] END DESC,
CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 1 AND @orderdir = 'asc'  THEN items.[CategoryValue] END ASC,
CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 2 AND @orderdir = 'desc' THEN items.[CreatedOn]     END DESC,
CASE WHEN @orderColumn = 2 AND @orderdir = 'asc'  THEN items.[CreatedOn]     END ASC

OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetProducts 
( 
    @OrderBy      VARCHAR(50), 
    @Input2       VARCHAR(30) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    SELECT Id, ProductName, Description, Price, Quantity 
    FROM Products 
    WHERE ProductName LIKE @Input2 
    ORDER BY 
        CASE             
            WHEN @OrderBy = 'ProductNameAsc' THEN ProductName 
        END ASC, 
        CASE 
            WHEN @OrderBy = 'ProductNameDesc' THEN ProductName 
        END DESC 

END
```

From here:

http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/21/dynamic-conditional-order-by-clause-in-sql-server-t-sql

> Ascending and Descending actions need
>   to be grouped into separate CASE
>   statements, separated with a comma. In
>   your server-side code/script make sure
>   to append 'Asc' or 'Desc' onto the
>   order by string, or you could have two
>   Stored procedure input parameters for
>   column name and order by direction if
>   you want.

Comment: can you please explain this END ASC, (comma) CASE syntax? If the input is ProductNameDesc, Won't it generate: .. ORDER BY ASC, ProductName DESC ? the "asc," following the end is the part of statement isn't it? – markiz 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

Comment: I don't actually know, I just googled to find that article.  Gary's response below seems to use the same technique.

Comment: hey markiz, you should just *try* it.  You're basically saying you don't believe that what this article suggests will work, so just give it a go, I bet it will work just fine.

Comment: Presumably the logic goes something like this:  Each CASE statement is evaluated, if none of the WHEN statements in the CASE statement are triggered then the entire CASE statement is ignored, including the trailing ASC.

Comment: @markiz & Alex: If none of the WHEN conditions evaluate true and there is no ELSE condition then entire CASE expression evaluates to null. Since all the rows will have null, that part of the ORDER BY clause will not change the order. If input is ProdcuctNameDesc the values sorted on for every row will be NULL sorted ASC and ProductName sorted DESC & ProductNameASC would sort by ProductName ASC, NULL Desc

Answer (score 4):

More compact version of accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147806/1548895), but as accepted answer this works fine only when result expressions after `THEN` have the same type.

```
ORDER BY
    CASE @OrderDirection WHEN 0 THEN
        CASE @sortColumn
           WHEN 'AddedDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), AddedDate)
           WHEN 'Visible' THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), Visible)
           WHEN 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBy
           WHEN 'Title' THEN Title
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE @OrderDirection WHEN 1 THEN
        CASE @sortColumn
           WHEN 'AddedDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(50), AddedDate)
           WHEN 'Visible' THEN CONVERT(varchar(2), Visible)
           WHEN 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBy
           WHEN 'Title' THEN Title
        END
    END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sorting in either ASC or DESC order, irrespective of datatype.

The first example sorts alphabetically, the second using numbers. The @direction variable denotes sort direction (0 = ASC or 1 = DESC) and [column] is the sort column.

This also works for multi-column sorting and you can hide the [row] column if placed in a further outer query.

```
DECLARE @direction BIT = 1 -- 0 = ASC or 1 = DESC

-- Text sort. 

SELECT 
    IIF(@direction = 0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column] ASC), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column] DESC)) [row]
    , *
FROM
(   -- your dataset.
    SELECT N'B' [column] 
    UNION SELECT N'C' 
    UNION SELECT N'A'
) [data] ORDER BY [row] 

-- Numeric sort.

SELECT 
IIF(@direction = 0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column] ASC), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [column] DESC)) [row],
*
FROM
(   -- your dataset.
    SELECT 2 [column] 
    UNION SELECT 3 
    UNION SELECT 1
) [data] ORDER BY [row]
```