# Pagination ordering with variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This SQL statement is being flagged in SQL Server in the ORDER BY ' + @SortField + ' ' + @SortOrder + ' part.. Any ideas how can I fix it?

```
ALTER PROC [sbuser].[sp_MemberMailList ]
@MemberMailID bigint = null,
@FromMemberID bigint = null,
@ToMemberID bigint = null,
@Subject varchar(150) = null,
@Message varchar(8000) = null,
@FromDeletedFlag bit = null,
@ToDeletedFlag bit = null,
@FromArchivedFlag bit = null,
@ToArchivedFlag bit = null,
@ReadFlag bit = null,
@SQL nvarchar(4000) = null,
@SortField varchar(100) = null,
@SortOrder varchar(25) = null,
@NotificationSent bit = null,
@MemberID bigint = null,
@OnHold bit = 0,
@SpecialMail varchar(1) = 'N',
@PageSize float = null,
@PageNum int = 1,
@TotalPages float = null,
@StartDate datetime = null,
@EndDate datetime = null,
@MODE varchar(50)

AS

IF @MODE = 'INBOX-MAIL'
BEGIN
    SELECT @TotalPages = COUNT(*)/@PageSize
    FROM MemberMail a
    INNER JOIN Member b ON b.MemberID = a.FromMemberID
    WHERE a.ToMemberID = @ToMemberID
    AND a.ToDeletedFlag = 0
    AND a.OnHold = 0
    AND a.ToArchivedFlag = 0;

    WITH InMails AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @SortField + ' ' + @SortOrder + ') AS RowNum,
        a.MemberMailID,
        a.FromMemberID,
        a.Subject,
        a.CreateDate,
        b.UserName,
        a.ToReadFlag,
        b.Firstname,
        b.Lastname,
        b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName
        FROM MemberMail a
        INNER JOIN Member b ON b.MemberID = a.FromMemberID
        WHERE a.ToMemberID = @ToMemberID
        AND a.ToDeletedFlag = 0
        AND a.OnHold = 0
        AND a.ToArchivedFlag = 0
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM InMails
    WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize
    ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
END
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a field or sort direction with a variable. The entire SQL statement needs to be a dynamic string to do this.

So

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    ORDER BY [field expression] asc|desc) AS RowNum
```

Is fine, as is

```
exec('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(' + 
    'ORDER BY ' + @SortField + ' ' + @SortOrder + ') AS RowNum ...')
```

But

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    ORDER BY ' + @SortField + ' ' + @SortOrder + ') AS RowNum
```

Can't be handled by the query compiler in SQL.

Comment: Any ideas how I can resolve this?  Could really use the help here please.

Comment: @neojakey - either of the first two options will work. Basically you have either static fields in the `order by`, or the entire statement has to be a dynamic string. This is because what you choose to `order by` can completely change the query plan and how it's optimised, so there's no value to SQL in caching it.

Comment: @neojakey - there is one way to get round that, but it's nasty. Your sproc can only have sort fields that are in your `MemberMail` or `Member` tables, so you could repeat the entire statement for each sortable field. That'll be very ugly code, but will give SQL query plans that it can cache.

Comment: I repeated the entire statement 2 times for ASC and DESC.  Many thanks for your assistance..!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @SortField + '   ' + @SortOrder + ') AS RowNum,
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    string #1              string #2

                                                      ^---no operator
```

Unless you've got an outer string not shown in your code sample, you cannot build up an order by clause like this. You've got two different quoted strings with a space between then.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically changing the fields `ORDER BY` the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function. You can't do it the way you're trying.

You need to use dynamic SQL to accomplish what you're trying. You should  read  [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to get a good understanding of the mechanics as well as how to protect yourself from SQL Injection.

If for some reason you don't want to use dynamic SQL you can generate a giant case statement. For example this sample below taken from gbn's answer to [Dynamic order direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147763/dynamic-order-direction).

```
SELECT
     Columns you actually want
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         Columns you actually want,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AddedDate) AS AddedDateSort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Visible) AS VisibleSort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AddedBy) AS AddedBySort,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title) AS TitleSort
    FROM
         myTable
    WHERE
         MyFilters...
    ) foo
ORDER BY
     CASE @OrderByColumn
        WHEN 'AddedDate' THEN AddedDateSort
        WHEN 'Visible' THEN VisibleSort    
        WHEN 'AddedBy' THEN AddedBySort
        WHEN 'Title' THEN TitleSort
     END * @multiplier;
```

If you do that you should be on the lookout for performance issues since indexes may not be used for the sorting.

Comment: Nice solution - you could simplify it further with a sub query where the `case` switch is a selection. Then you have the `row_number()` function across that.